# Advice on mapping tiles to a height map/3D world

Tags: 3d, graphics, tilemap, grid

I've been attempting to think of a way to map tiles to a height map. Where a grid can be either layered or integrated into the world data. However, since I am not using voxels I could use some advice on where to start or look into on doing something like this.

For example a 16x16 grid layout on 3D world data.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by mapping tiles to a height map? Something like this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HrXu1pQanx4

Comment: @NilsOleTimm , I suppose that example works fairly well. I would however like to represent the tiles in a data structure. Basically a method of mapping each tile to the world. To refine my question a bit more. How would I form this grid on the height map into a data structure. I need advice primarily on how to actually map the world to a usable data-defined grid.

Comment: To be honest, I am not sure what you mean by "form into a data structure". How do you think it could work without a data structure. You have me utterly confused here.

Comment: Here's a better example of what I'm trying to do. https://youtu.be/HXjVtRMjUiA?t=2m19s  . I want to achieve that similar "grid" layout when he starts placing that pylon, and the pylon basically takes up 4 tiles.

Comment: There is a thing called tile mapping. But that is not what you mean. The data structure you want is a 2-dimensional array. The calculations for breaking your game world into discrete pieces like that are trivial. (Integer division)